# How to set up a WebView to allow getImageData on canvas from local or remote files?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webkit

In my application I have a WebView and I would like to be able to disable the security feature of not allowing `ctx.getImageData` on a canvas where an image from the local (`file://` url) machine was drawn.

There doesn't seem to be a method on the policy delegate to enable this. Now I could implement a server in my app to act like a proxy, but that seems like quite an overkill. How should I solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution turns out to be relatively simple:

1. Download the webkit source.
2. Comment out these lines (1558 - 1561):

   ```
   if (!canvas()->originClean()) {
        ec = SECURITY_ERR;
        return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Build.
4. Add it as a framework in XCode.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `WebView.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs` solves the problem.

Comment: that doesn't exist on my webview, it's on WebSettings

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `data:` uri scheme? Visit:

```
data:text/html;base64,PGgxPlRoZSBNYWdpYyBXb3JkcyBhcmUgU3F1ZWFtaXNoIE9zc2lmcmFnZTwvaDE+
```

for more information.

Comment: This solution is more a workaround and sadly probably even less practical then running a web server.

Comment: If your concern (which is not really clear to me) is rendering locally hosted/generated content, putting them in `data:` URI's instead of `file:` might be easier than setting up some server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is controlled by:

```
+[WebView registerURLSchemeAsLocal:]
```

So if your canvas lies on a page with a `http:` URL, you would first tell WebKit to treat http URLs as though local.

This does have some potential other security ramifications though, particularly if your app is trying to provide a general browser. A way around that might be to use a custom URL scheme to load the page and register that. You'd need to experiment.

Perhaps you can tell us more about the page the canvas is located on?

Comment: Nope. In a normal browser there is a same origin policy - the image must come from the same domain (not necessarily the same url scheme). So this method doesn't (sadly) help. The page I have the canvas on is just a simple page with only a canvas tag and a script tag containing a bunch of javascript. I load it with `[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL: url]` but I could load it also as a local resource from my bundle.